# Office 2013 Service Pack 1 - Is it possible to remove some parts of it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange-2010

I recently allowed the Office 2013 Service Pack 1 to be installed through Windows update to my computer. However, in combination with my company's Exchange server, it leads to a very annoying "bug" that consists in repeated, very annoying credentials prompts in Outlook (although the connection to the mailbox is effectively established and works). This bug has been reported on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d02c095e-f40f-4aa6-9114-90b98a534edb/outlook-2013-patch-of-november-12-2013-makes-outlook-repeatedly-prompt-for-credentials?forum=officeitpro) and in other places.

Prior to Service Pack 1, I could simply uninstall the one Microsoft patch that caused this behavior. With Service Pack 1, it is embedded in it and I do not seem to find a way to remove just that component of the Service Pack.

Is there any chance it can still be done?

Comment: No; they rolled all the updates into a single update.

Comment: The unpatched files could be restored as long as you have access to the original, pre-SP1 files. Considering the patch is meant to fix a security vulnerability, it would be to better wait till Microsoft addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to remove parts of any Microsoft Service Pack including Office 2013 SP 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it absolutely is possible to remove Outlook 2013 SP1. I just did it. Go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, View installed updates (on left), then click on the Outlook 2013 update(s) you want to remove, and click Uninstall at the top.

Thank goodness, because SP1 rendered my Amicus Attorney software completely non-functional. Removing SP1 worked like a charm.

Comment: Uou may have to recreate the Office Document Cache after uninstalling SP1